# Labels in UITableView's cells are not wrapped until scrolling starts

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout

I have a UITableView with a prototype cell that has two labels inside of it. There are 16 hard-coded text strings of various size in 16 cells (the point is for them to wrap). When the view loads originally, I see the second label in each cell is not wrapped:

[image]

When I scroll down, the text is wrapped correctly:

[image]

When I scroll back up, the cells are wrapped correctly.. I can post more info (like code) but I'm hoping the solution is obvious to someone and that's not necessary.

This is in iOS 8.

**Update - here's some code! **

```
//  TestViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@end

//  TestViewController.m
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "TestViewController.h"
#import "MessageCell.h"

@interface TestViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *titles;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *messages;

@property IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end

@implementation TestViewController

-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 66.0;

    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

    self.titles = @[
                    @"One",
                    @"Two Two",
                    @"Three Three Three",
                    @"Four Four Four Four",
                    @"Five Five Five Five Five",
                    @"Six Six Six Six Six Six",
                    @"Seven Seven Seven Seven Seven Seven Seven",
                    @"Eight Eight Eight Eight Eight Eight Eight Eight",
                    @"Nine",
                    @"Ten",
                    @"Eleven",
                    @"Twelve",
                    @"Thirteen",
                    @"Fourteen",
                    @"Fifteen",
                    @"Sixteen",
                    ];
    self.messages = @[
                      @"This is a short message.",
                      @"This is a long message. It's longer than the medium sized message so we can see how it looks with the wrapping and dynamic sized cells.",
                      @"This is a medium sized message. It's not going to be very long.",
                      @"This is a long message. It's longer than the medium sized message so we can see how it looks with the wrapping and dynamic sized cells.",
                      @"This is a short message.",
                      @"This is a long message. It's longer than the medium sized message so we can see how it looks with the wrapping and dynamic sized cells.",
                      @"This is a medium sized message. It's not going to be very long.",
                      @"This is a long message. It's longer than the medium sized message so we can see how it looks with the wrapping and dynamic sized cells.",
                      @"This is a short message.",
                      @"This is a long message. It's longer than the medium sized message so we can see how it looks with the wrapping and dynamic sized cells.",
                      @"This is a medium sized message. It's not going to be very long.",
                      @"This is a long message. It's longer than the medium sized message so we can see how it looks with the wrapping and dynamic sized cells.",
                      @"This is a short message.",
                      @"This is a long message. It's longer than the medium sized message so we can see how it looks with the wrapping and dynamic sized cells.",
                      @"This is a medium sized message. It's not going to be very long.",
                      @"This is a short message.",
                      ];

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"in number of rows. returning: %ul", [self.messages count]);
    return [self.messages count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"in cell for row: %ld", (long)indexPath.row);

    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MessageCell";
    MessageCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[MessageCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.title.text = [self.titles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.message.text = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: Nothing is  obvious. Post your UITableview datasource code.

Comment: I've fixed problems similar to this by calling [self layoutIfNeeded] in an override of didMoveToSuperview (in the  custom cell class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614919/uitableviewcell-not-wrapping-text-correctly-when-first-loaded-but-does-when-scr).

The solution is to make sure I call `[cell.contentView layoutIfNeeded];` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in my table view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I also found that `layoutIfNeeded` was the answer but I think it only needs to be called once on initial cell creation. In my case in `awakeFromNib` but somewhere else may be appropriate if you aren't using Interface Builder.